# Python pandas checking if row contains a string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a program that would sort found password hashes with CSV file containing hash and email. I am trying to get the "Email" from ex.csv and "Pass" from the found.txt where hash values coincide. But I am getting an error - `raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

My code -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ex = pd.read_csv("ex.csv",delimiter=",")
found = pd.read_csv("found.txt",delimiter=":")

temp = ex[["Hash","Email"]]
te = found[["Hash","Pass"]]

for index,row in te.iterrows(): #Looping through file
    if temp.loc[temp['Hash'] == row['Hash'][index]]: # If pandas can't locate Hash string inside a first file, list is empty. And I am comparing that here
        print(temp['Email'][index]) # If successful, print out the
        print(te['Pass'][index])    # found values in the console
```

Samples from ex.csv:

```
                                          Hash                    Email
0     210ac64b3c5a570e177b26bb8d1e3e93f72081fd  example@example.com
1     707a1b7b7d9a12112738bcef3acc22aa09e8c915  example@example.com
2     24529d87ea25b05daba92c2b7d219a470c3ff3a0  example@example.com
```

Samples from found.txt:

```
                                         Hash         Pass
0    f8fa3b3da3fc71e1eaf6c18e4afef626e1fc7fc1     pass1
1    ecdc5a7c21b2eb84dfe498657039a4296cbad3f4     pass2
2    f61946739c01cff69974093452057c90c3e0ba14     pass3
```

Or maybe there are better ways to iterate through rows and check if the row contains string from another file row? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print matches, use the following code:

```
for _, row in te.iterrows():
    rowHash = row.Hash
    matches = temp.Hash == rowHash  # boolean mask
    if matches.any():
        mails = temp[matches].Email.tolist()
        print(f'Found:  {rowHash} / {row.Pass} / {", ".join(mails)}')
```

Thoroughly compare my code with yours.
I think, such comparison will allow you to locate what was wrong in your code.

You didn't write it precisely, but I suppose that your error occurred in
`if` instruction (my version is different).

## Edit

You can also try another concept. Due to lookup by index it should run
considerably faster than the above loop.

```
# Set 'Hash' column as the index in both DataFrames
temp2 = temp.set_index('Hash')
te2 = te.set_index('Hash')
# Loop over rows in 'te2', index (Hash) in 'teHash'
for teHash, row in te2.iterrows():
    try:
        res = temp2.loc[teHash]  # Attempt to find corresponding row(s) in 'temp2'
        if isinstance(res, pd.Series):  # Single match found
            mails = res.Email
        else:                           # Multiple matches found
            mails = ', '.join(res.Email)
        print(f'Found: {teHash} / {row.Pass} / {mails}')
    except KeyError:
        pass      # Not found
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ex = pd.read_csv("c.csv",delimiter=",")
found = pd.read_csv("d.csv",delimiter=",")

print(ex)
print(found)

temp = ex[['Hash','Email']]
te = found[['Hash','Pass']]

for temp1, temp2 in zip(te.iterrows(), temp.iterrows()):
    if temp2[1]['Hash'][temp2[0]] == temp1[1]['Hash'][temp1[0]]:
        print(temp['Email'][temp2[0]])
        print(te['Pass'][temp1[0]])
```

I have stored values like this

1) c.csv

```
Hash,Email
210ac64b3c5a570e177b26bb8d1e3e93f72081fd,example@example.com
707a1b7b7d9a12112738bcef3acc22aa09e8c915,example@example.com
24529d87ea25b05daba92c2b7d219a470c3ff3a0,example@example.com
```

2) d.csv

```
Hash,Pass
f8fa3b3da3fc71e1eaf6c18e4afef626e1fc7fc1,pass1
ecdc5a7c21b2eb84dfe498657039a4296cbad3f4,pass2
f61946739c01cff69974093452057c90c3e0ba14,pass3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But with your code I am getting error - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 14, in <module>
    if temp['Hash'].str == row['Hash'][index]:
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @Mike2233 I am considering size of both dataframe as same.

Comment: Ohh. That's why. ex.csv file is bigger. But I am not getting any prints at all. It just jumps to index out of range

Comment: @Mike2233 I have edited the code but looks like answer by Valdi_Bo is quite better and does the work easily.